# Enabling account deletion on nats server

Tags: nats.io

I was trying to prune some users from my nats server by doing:

```
nsc push --system-account SYS -u nats://localhost:4222 -P
```

but I got the following error:

> server nats-comm-2 responded with error: delete accounts request by SOME_KEY_VALUE failed - delete must be enabled in server config

The meaning of the error is pretty obvious, when I examine the help documentation for `nsc push -P`:

> Only works with nats-resolver enabled nats-server. Mutually exclusive of account-removal/diff

But I'm not sure how to enable this in my nats server config. How do I allow for account pruning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found documentation in the resolver section, [here](https://docs.nats.io/running-a-nats-service/configuration/securing_nats/auth_intro/jwt/resolver#nats-based-resolver), showing that I could add `allow_delete: true` to the config, but as the YAML format is in camel-case, I had to modify it to be `allowDelete: true` instead.

```yaml
nats:
  auth:
    enabled: true
    resolver:
      type: full
      allowDelete: true
```